# How to avoid the redefinition of a function (PEP8 error F811)

Tags: python

I have the following code inside a Python function:

```
strings = ('TIRS10', 'TIRS11')
if any(string in fields for string in strings):

    def transform(row):
        '''
        Transform an input row in to a named tuple, then feed it in to a
        dictionary.
        '''
        # split row in elements
        elements = row.split('|')

        # key: 1st column, replace
        key = replace_dot_comma_space(elements[0])

        # namedtuple
        ect = namedtuple(key, [fields[0], fields[1]])

        # feed namedtuples
        ect.TIRS10 = is_number(elements[1])
        ect.TIRS11 = is_number(elements[2])

        # feed dictionary
        dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, ect)

strings = ('b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7')
if any(string in fields for string in strings):

    def transform(row):
        '''
        Transform an input row in to a named tuple, then feed it in to a
        dictionary.
        '''
        # split row in elements
        elements = row.split('|')

        # key: 1st column, replace
        key = replace_dot_comma_space(elements[0])

        # *** small modification for the CWV field ***
        fields[0] = 'cwv'

        # named tuples
        cwv = namedtuple(key,
                         [replace_dot_comma_space(fields[0]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[1]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[2]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[3]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[4]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[5]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[6]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[7]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[8]),
                          replace_dot_comma_space(fields[9])])

        # feed named tuples
        cwv.subrange = to_tuple(elements[1])
        cwv.b0 = is_number(elements[2])
        cwv.b1 = is_number(elements[3])
        cwv.b2 = is_number(elements[4])
        cwv.b3 = is_number(elements[5])
        cwv.b4 = is_number(elements[6])
        cwv.b5 = is_number(elements[7])
        cwv.b6 = is_number(elements[8])
        cwv.b7 = is_number(elements[9])
        cwv.rmse = is_number(elements[10])
        dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, cwv)  # feed dictionary

map(transform, rows)
return dictionary
```

and I get, for it, a *redefinition of unused 'transform' from line xxx [F811]*. How can I tackle this "error" so as to not use two different functions, but only one, later on inside the same function?  What is the correct way to approach such a case?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your formatting.  Are the last two lines meant to be outdented one block?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching it.

Comment: This question is more suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to just name them as transform1 and transform2 and put map inside if-else:

```
if condition1:
    transform = transform1
else:  # if condition2
    transform = transform2

map(transform, row)
```

Also, it is not good to reuse variables like strings: it could introduce subtle errors. It is also not good to change dictionary variable implicitely. It is always better to pass such things explicitely and return changed objects also explicitely.

If there are more transforms like the above, it's cleaner to refactor is object-oriented style where .transform() is a method of tirs-class or b-class. Then dictionary will be naturally an attribute, part of the Transformer class state, and not global.

Comment: Thanks, sounds practical. The exposition of the named tuple into the outer world (outside of the function/class) is wanted. It's meant to give the freedom to a user/scripter to call the attributes of the object in question easily, with their actual name. Does this count as an explanation?

Comment: The more like data-driven approach as opposed to OOP is perfectly fine. However, even in this case it is much better to be explicit with dictionary as an argument (and result) to processing functions such as transforms. And I guess quality is the concern here because why bother with pyflakes warnings otherwise.