# PEP8-conform coding style when importing text fixtures (F401 + F811)

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, flake8

Sometimes I use a [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) defined in another module (probably because I want to re-use it in multiple places).  As a minimal artificial example, the structure would be something like this:

**`mwe20.py`**:

```py
def circle(pi, r):
    return pi*r**2
```

**`test_mwe20a.py`**:

```py
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def pi():
    return 3
```

`test_mwe20b.py`:

```py
from test_mwe20a import pi


def test_circle(pi):
    from mwe20 import circle
    assert circle(pi, 2) == 12
```

This runs fine: `pytest test_mwe20b.py` will run one test, which will pass.  However `flake8` complains.  Running `flake8 test_mwe20b.py` gives:

```
test_mwe20b.py:1:1: F401 'test_mwe20a.pi' imported but unused
test_mwe20b.py:4:17: F811 redefinition of unused 'pi' from line 1
```

I can of course add noqa directives to shut up flake8, such that `test_mwe20b.py` looks like:

```py
from test_mwe20a import pi  # noqa: F401


def test_circle(pi):  # noqa: F811
    from mwe20 import circle
    assert circle(pi, 2) == 12
```

but I want to make sure there is no other way.

What is the PEP8-conform way to use fixtures defined in another module?  Or is my code actually PEP8-conform and is this a limitation of flake8?  The only related issue I find is closed and [about the line number for the F811 warning](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/432), not for the fact that it warns in the first place.

See also: [Why I'm getting F811 error in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50268284/974555) for a poorly phrased and incorrectly answered related question.

Comment: You don't need to import the fixtures to use them, `pytest` will resolve them by itself. Since you use the fixture `pi` in several test modules, create a file `conftest.py` in the tests root dir and move the fixture function in there, it will also be resolved automatically.

Comment: @hoefling Yep — I found about the `conftest.py` magic after I wrote the question in what I then linked as a duplicate.